# How to change bits in byte with python?

Tags: python, io, type-conversion, bit

I have `.bmp` picture and I need to make some steganography with it.

For this action I have to convert `.bmp` to list of bytes and then make some changes in bits.

I use `open()` with `"rb"` parameter to make bytes list and then convert each byte to string using `'{0:08b}'.format(mybyte)`.

**My question is how to convert this string representation of byte back to byte?** maybe there are some faster or more correct ways to work with bits?

Comment: What exactly do you need to do?

Comment: You want a [bit string or bit array](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+bit+array+or+bitstring).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int` constructor can do this very easily :

```
>>> s = '{0:08b}'.format(42)
>>> s
'00101010'
>>> int(s, 2)
42
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [binascii](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html) module.

Ex:

```
binascii.a2b_hex('A0')
```